# typescript compilation error - "Value of type ... is not indexable by type ..."

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Using typescript 2.0.6.0

I have an interface defined:

```
interface indexesWorkData {
    pointInTime: number;
    numberOfIndexesWorking: number;
}
```

This is my class:

```
class work {         
    indexesWork: Array<indexesWorkData> = [];

    pushRange(startTime: number, endTime: number) {

        let indexStart = this.indexesWork.findIndex(x => x.pointInTime >= someNumber);
        if (this.indexesWork[indexStart].pointInTime === anotherNumber) {
            // Do stuff
        } 
    }
}
```

I get compilation error: 
"Value of type indexesWorkData[] is not indexable by type indexesWorkData"
for trying to access `this.indexesWork[indexStart`]

But at runtime it works and indexStart has correct value.

Why is that ?

Comment: You didn't put the code inside any method.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors using your code (other than `someNumber` and `anotherNumber` being undefined, which was an easy fix). Are you able to maybe try a newer version of typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to explicitly tell the compile about the type of `indexStart`?

```
let indexStart: number = <number>this.indexesWork.findIndex(x => x.pointInTime >= someNumber);
```

Comment: This is also not working. The error you get now is on the findIndex() method, that it cannot convert 'indexesWorkData' to a 'number'

Comment: I added a type assertion to my answer. Could you try it with the assertion?

Comment: @Danielle: My guess is that findIndex() returns any and therefore the inferred type indexStart is also any which won't work as an index alter on.

Comment: No, same error even when using <number>, still getting 'cannot convert 'indexesWorkData' to a 'number'